# OData $batch from Postman

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, postman

I am trying to post OData batch request in postman.

The url:

```
http://localhost:52484/$batch
```

Header:

```
Content-Type : multipart/mixed; boundary=batch_36522ad7-fc75-4b56-8c71-56071383e77b
```

Body (raw) :

```
--batch_36522ad7-fc75-4b56-8c71-56071383e77b 
 Content-Type: application/http 
 Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary 

 GET /Schools?$top=1
 Host: host   

--batch_36522ad7-fc75-4b56-8c71-56071383e77b
```

But am getting the below error:

```
{
"Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:52484/%24batch'.",
"MessageDetail": "No route providing a controller name was found to match request URI 'http://localhost:52484/%24batch'"
}
```

Any idea about what is missing in the request?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you configure OData route and batchHandler correctly, something like the below:

```
ODataBatchHandler odataBatchHandler = new DefaultODataBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer);
odataBatchHandler.MessageQuotas.MaxOperationsPerChangeset = 10;
odataBatchHandler.MessageQuotas.MaxPartsPerBatch = 10;

config.MapODataServiceRoute(
    routeName: "ODataRoute",
    routePrefix: null,
    model: builder.GetEdmModel(),
    batchHandler: odataBatchHandler
    );
```